# Is there any way to make join faster, when dealing large amount of data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join

I am using mongo and nodejs.

Current I have the following collections:

```
entryMore {
entryId
...
}

filesize {
entryId
...
}

entryIam {
entryId
...
}

entryStatus {
entryId
...
}

entryPubStatus {
entryId
....
}
```

They are all one to one mapping with entryId

I am joining all of the collections in nodejs with the following code

```
// db
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const fs = require('fs');
const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;


// run catch err
run()
  .catch(error => console.error(error.stack));


async function run() {
  // connect
  const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017');

  // db
  const db = client.db('kal');

  // The only way to use `$lookup` in MongoDB 3.2 and 3.4
  const docs = await db.collection('entryMore').aggregate([

    // filesize
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'filesize',
        localField: 'entryId',
        foreignField: 'entryId',
        as: 'filesize'
      }
    },
    {
      // deconstruct and map to one by one
      $unwind: '$filesize'
    },

    // Iam
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'entryIam',
        localField: 'entryId',
        foreignField: 'entryId',
        as: 'entryIam'
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$entryIam'
    },

    // entry status
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'entryStatus',
        localField: 'entryId',
        foreignField: 'entryId',
        as: 'entryStatus'
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$entryStatus'
    },

    // pub status
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'entryPubStatus',
        localField: 'entryId',
        foreignField: 'entryId',
        as: 'entryPubStatus'
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$entryPubStatus'
    },

     // Final
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        entryId: 1,
        name: 1,
        //description: 1,
        userId: 1,

        creatorId: 1,
        msDuration: 1,
        categories: 1,
        categoriesIds: 1,

        createdAt: 1,
        updatedAt: 1,
        tags: 1,
        downloadUrl: 1
      }
    }

  ]);

  const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({field});
  const csv = json2csvParser.parse(docs);

  await writeFile('./csv/entrySheet.csv', csv);
  console.log('done!');
  process.exit(); 
}
```

Each collection has **97k records**. It takes whole date to generate the csv. I wonder is there any way to improve it?

Comment: Don't join. That really is the best way to make anything fast. Why are all these things in separate collections anyway? And especially considering that your use case here is producing a single denormalized source! MongoDB is not an RDBMS and should not be used as one. There is embedding and a whole host of other options as the main reason why you should have selected it in the first place. The only thing that can "speed up" from here otherwise is "indexes", and there simply isn't any `$match` condition in place, so we can rule that out. In short. You're doing it wrong.

Comment: @kenpeter your schema is really not good. I really recomending you to read '6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design' (
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what is written by @NeilLunn. But to still clarify your questions, `$lookup` performs an equality match on the foreignField to the localField from the input documents. If a document in the from collection does not contain the foreignField, the `$lookup` treats the value as null for matching purposes.
So go ahead and create an index on your foreign field so you'll be doing 97k index hits and not 97k table scans. It is bound to get the time way lower